# My Indian flapshell turtle fell from 3rd floor. How to know there's any internal damage by his behaviour?

Tags: reptiles, turtles, injury

[image]

I also want to say only one drop blood came out.
Then I took him in dry place.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! You can not tell from the behavior, not early enought to help him. Only a vet could see, for example with x-ray, if there is liquid (blood) at places, where no liquid should be in the inside. If your turtle change its behavior, then it is too late to help him. See a vet!

Comment: It is impossible to tell until it's too late, and especially considering that turtles have incredibly slow metabolism compared to other popular pets. For example, after receiving fatal injuries a hamster is expected to die after a few hours, but in case of a turtle/tortoise it could be even after a few weeks, and by that time some people couldn't even remember and relate its death with the accident that has happened so long ago.

Comment: It depends: 1. A very small turtle will suffer less damage than a large one 2. Where did the blood come from? The mouth, the anus, or through the skin or shell?

Comment: See a vet. You need an MRI to be sure. Is a turtle really worth that expense though?

Answer (score 21):

It's impossible to tell if an animal - especially a reptile like a turtle - has internal injuries from it's behavior, unless it's currently dying. A vet must examine the animal to find internal damage.

That "only a single drop of blood" came out of a wound can mean 2 things:

- Either the wound didn't bleed very much
- Or the rest of the blood pooled beneath the shell because it couldn't flow out. In that case it's impossible to tell how much bleeding there was and if it stopped or is still bleeding. You need medical equipment like x-ray or ultrasound to examine the wound.

Almost all animals hide injuries as much as possible, especially wild animals. In the wild, predators target preferably slow and defenceless prey, so old, young and injured animals are targeted first. To increase their chances of survival, injured animals have to hide their injuries from predators. Only if the injury is so severe that they cannot hide it any longer will they show any change in behavior. Unfortunately this often means that even a vet cannot help them anymore.

If you have the chance to see a vet, you should definitely do so as soon as possible. Even during Corona lockdowns many vets still open their clinics, but you may have to call in advance.
If there is no vet around, all you can do is give your turtle a calm place to recuperate with as little stress as you can manage.

Comment: How much time it will survive maximum if there is any internal damage as per you ?

Comment: @KrishnenduAdak Again, that's impossible to tell. If a major blood vessel ruptures (like the aorta) a person or animal can die in minutes from internal bleeding without external signs of injury. If your turtle heals now but the shell was damaged in a way that it cannot grow any longer, it may take several years until the shell (that is then too small for the animal that will have grown) puts pressure on organs and contributes to a premature death. And there's always the small possibility that everything heals perfectly fine and won't cause problems, but you shouldn't rely on that chance.

Comment: Because some people compare the behavior of cats/dogs/rabbits/turtles and all other pets without differentiation: Maybe you could add that this behavior (to hide hurts/illness) is typical for prey animals. Because for example cats and dogs could show (their trusted persons) their illness by behavior, to get comfort from them

Comment: I don't know what I have to do now. Even there is no medical center in my area. Please suggest what I can do in this situation.

Comment: @KrishnenduAdak If there is no vet in your area, you can only care for your turtle as good as possible and hope everything will be ok. If the turtle can move, eat and poop, there is no imminent danger of death anymore. Keep the wound dry to avoid infection (maybe offer very shallow water where the turtle can get wet but can't dive). Keep it seperate from other turtles for a while to avoid stress and feed it good quality food. Indian flapshells are omnivores, so offer insects or tiny fishes to include protein and mineals in the diet that help heal the shell. And make sure it cannot fall again.

Comment: Do you find any improvement. Please see this picture.          https://photos.app.goo.gl/bCegUGiZbithW7d86

Comment: @Elmy some turtles can only swallow, if they are under water. I do not know exactly for this kind. This should be considered When the turtle do not eat well

Comment: Please see this picture.     https://photos.app.goo.gl/bCegUGiZbithW7d86.                   Do you find any improvement ?

Comment: @KrishnenduAdak I'm not a vet and I don't know if it improved or not. It will probably take a long time to heal, like a fractured bone. At least it looks like a clean fracture, which is a good sign.